# Why is Windows 11 not supported on my hardware?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-preview

I installed Microsoft's "PC Health Check" app to see if my computer is compatible with Windows 11, but it just says "This PC can't run Windows 11".  It doesn't tell me why.

I have relatively modern specs so I don't know why it would say this.  I also checked with the official required specs, but my computer still fits inside that window as well.  I am running Windows 10 in UEFI mode. Does anyone know what I need to upgrade to support Windows 11?

[image: Here is the message.]

[image]

Specs:

CPU - Intel Core i7-10700F
GPU - MSI RTX 2060 6GB
RAM - 16GB DDR4
Storage - 512GB NVMe and 2TB Seagate HD
Motherboard - B460M Pro-VDH WiFi

I have checked Windows security settings and it shows this:

[image: settings]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the reason, why my PC can't run Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1658900/how-to-find-out-the-reason-why-my-pc-cant-run-windows-11)

Comment: Not really.  That is an issue with an older processor, while mine is the latest version.  The answer below should answer my question, but I'll have to try it when I get home to be sure.

Comment: @Salocor - I strongly disagree it’s not a duplicate.  Your screenshot clearly indicates you have not enabled TPM functionality.  The Microsoft compatibility tool was updated today and now indicates why your system isn’t compatible with Windows 11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my computer run Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I checked Windows security settings, and it shows this:
> [image]
> Does anyone know what I need to upgrade to support Windows 11?

You have not enabled your motherboard's Intel Platform Trust Technology (Intel PTT) that allows you to use a firmware-based TPM 2.0 feature of your processor.  Windows 11 does not explicitly require BitLocker.  Enabling Intel PTT will satisfy the requirements for TPM 2.0 support.

Once you have enabled the feature within the Security submenu within your firmware, and you run tpm.msc, you will be present with the following window.

[image]

Your system meets all the other [system requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications) and most likely would run Windows 11 without any issue. If you cannot enable Intel PTT on your motherboard, that means your system isn't compatible with the base Windows 11 image.

If you still get the same message even after you have enabled PTT, make sure your local account is linked to a Microsoft Account.  What I am reading is that it might be a requirement for the tool. While the documentation says it's required for Windows 11 Home (although there are currently workarounds to that), there is a good chance the requirement is being flagged with the tool even if you are using Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: It is currently possible, to bypass the TPM 2.0 check, by replacing appraiserres.dll contained within the leaked Windows 11 Insider Preview build ISO with the one from a Windows 10 ISO.  However, what is not known at this time, is if TPM 2.0 is required for some feature that isn't explicitly documented at this time.